# Nonetype error while saving file with dropzone js in Django

Tags: python, django, dropzone.js

I am trying to save documents/images into my SQL database using dropzone.js ,for my web app made using Django

HTML FILE:

```
{% extends 'Main/logged_base_expert.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
    
<head>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" media="screen">

<form action="{% url 'document_upload' %}" method = "POST" class="dropzone dz" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" multiple >
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


  <!-- client section end -->
    <!-- footer section start -->
{% endblock %}
```

views.py :

```
def document_upload(request):
    c = main.objects.get(username = request.session['username'])
    unq_id = c.unq_id
    print("overall")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        images = request.FILES.get('file')
        print("image")
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(images.name, images)
        Doc1 = Doc(user_id = unq_id, upload = images)
        Doc1.save()

    return render(request, 'Main/document_upload.html')
```

models.py:

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    unq_id  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    upload  = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'expert/images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.unq_id)
```

The issue I keep facing is that , i keep getting the error

```
AttributeError at /document_upload/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

It  occurs in the following line, in views.py:

```
filename = fs.save(images.name, images)
```

Additional Info : the relative path of the image seems to be storing just perfectly in the database, but since i keep getting the error , i am unable to redirect the app to another page

Answer (score 0):

you're getting AttributeError because this couldn't be found in your request - request.FILES.get('file'). Print request.FILES and see what you have in there.

Comment: <MultiValueDict: {'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.JPG (image/jpeg)>]}>
<MultiValueDict: {}>
 It is printing twice and the second time there aint any name